# The current value is not saved after a re edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, edit, parameters

I have a problem with my re-edition. Let me explain it : When I edit and update an object current value is ok in my show view. But if i re-edit current value isn't the last selected.

Problem is only with checkbox or select.

My form

```
<%= f.fields_for :situations do |s| %>

<p><label for="plage">Plage</label>
<%= s.select :plage?, ["", "oui","non"] %> à <%= s.select :distanceplage?, ["", "moins de 1", "2","3", "4", "5 et plus"] %> km</p>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def edit

end

 def update
      @camping = Camping.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @camping.update(camping_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @camping, notice: 'Camping was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @camping }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @camping.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

How i can fix it ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think the current value in the database is good. Have you checked it? It's just you don't preload the selector with the database value. You create a new blank tag instead...

Comment: Yes current value is good. Problem is only on display select and check box. If i add text_field value is ok... I dont know why...

Comment: Sorry, I am not in front of my computer but I think I managed to do this with a selector_tag and option_for_select option. Someone may post full answer. If not I come back to you tomorrow on this to tell you my solution.

Comment: @Maxence Thanks, I hope that someone can help me for this.

Comment: Selector_tag and check_box_tag are not easy to play with. Always check the html produced each time you modify these tags. Bon courage

Comment: Merci :) I will read some documentation !

Comment: Is not the full solution, but :include_blank => true display current value for "oui" but not for "non"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some search solution is this :

```
:include_blank => true
```

so my view looks like this

```
<p><label for="plage">Plage</label>
<%= s.select :plage, ["oui","non"], :include_blank => true %> à <%= s.text_field :distanceplage %> km</p>
```